# Web Assembly emrun: command not found when running from batch script, but runs fine in command window

Tags: bash, webassembly

I managed to put together and run a hello world program Web Assembly, using Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu). Essentially following the getting started page found here: https://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/

I successfully ran the program with this command:

```
emrun --browser "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" --verbose --port 8081 hello.html
```

All is well and dandy when I run this in the command line, but when i made a script called start.sh that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Starting hello world in chrome."
emrun --browser "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" --verbose --port 8081 hello.html
```

I get the error mentioned in the title "emrun: commnand not found".

The first line "#!/usr/bin/env bash" was copied from one of the .sh files in the Wasm SDK, so I think its right? 
Ive also tried adding the Wasm SDK to the $PATH using the edit enviromnent variables manager windows 10 provides, but with no luck.

I dont have a lot of experience with batch scripts, and im not sure how to proceed from here.. I feel like im missing something obvious but I just cant figure out what the difference is between the console and the script file ?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer myself after some more head smashing! Thanks to all the memes I've seen i'll actually share the answer with you.

I edited the script so it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd ..
cd Wasm/emsdk
source ./emsdk_env.sh --build=Release
cd ..
cd ..
cd hello
emcc hello.c -o hello.html
echo "Starting hello world in chrome."
emrun --browser "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" --verbose --port 8081 hello.html
```

Running "$ sudo bash start.sh" now prints out the following message in the console:

```
Adding directories to PATH:
PATH += /home/elaurora/Wasm/emsdk
PATH += /home/elaurora/Wasm/emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten
PATH += /home/elaurora/Wasm/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin

Setting environment variables:
EMSDK = /home/elaurora/Wasm/emsdk
EM_CONFIG = /home/elaurora/.emscripten
EMSDK_NODE = /home/elaurora/Wasm/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node

Starting hello world in chrome.
... then a bunch of unrelated stuff regarding the server that was just started
```

Of course for this to work for you, you'll have to edit each of the paths so that the line

```
source ./emsdk_env.sh --build=Release
```

is run within the emsdk folder.

There is probably a better way to do this, perhaps a way involving permanently setting the correct PATH variables to have the above values, but unfortunately I am not sure how to go about this. 
Nonetheless, this solution is working for me.